# Using alternative text in script

Tags: javascript

How do I make the content of the script (see below) depend on the value of a variable, please?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready( function () {
   var ID = "<?php echo $ID ?>";
   $('#dataTable tfoot th.search').each( function () {
    [code that works]
  });
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        WHAT I WANT IS TO PUT "code section A" here if ID is true, or
        PUT "code section B" here if ID is false
        [more code that works]
    });
} );
</script>
```

Comment: `ID` is a string so it never is `true` or `false`.

Comment: @trincot exactly... OP wants the string to be evaluated as PHP which will return `$ID` which, hopefully, is a bool

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If you're rendering the difference in PHP then your condition is based on `$ID`, or if you're choosing the difference client-side then your condition is based on `ID`.  Either way you have the value you want to use in your conditional logic.  What did you try and what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript, `ID` is a string, so it will be always `true` unless if it is empty.

So, you have to remove the double quotes, the only issue is that `true` is in lower case in js but Upper Case (`True`) in php. the best way to do it is using some ternary operators:

```php
variable/condition ? [if True] : [if False]
```

I'll also use the php echo shorthand `<?= >` :

This :

```php
<?php echo whatever ?>
```

Becomes :

```php
<?= whatever ?>
```

So here's your script :

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready( function () {
   var ID = <?= $ID ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
   $('#dataTable tfoot th.search').each( function () {
    [code that works]
  });
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        <?= $ID ? "code section A" : "code section B" ?>
        [more code that works]
    });
} );
</script>
```

You can also do the check in JavaScript :

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready( function () {
   var ID = <?= $ID ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
   $('#dataTable tfoot th.search').each( function () {
    [code that works]
  });
    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        if (ID) {
            "code section A"
        } else {
            "code section B"
        }
        [more code that works]
    });
} );
</script>
```